# Мистер Георг, так как и Лео-мэтр(,) является небезынтересным

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

Нужны запятые?

`Мой кoток, также как и моя рыс(,) — это интересное животное.`

`Мистер Георг, так как и Лео-мэтр(,) является небезынтересным.`

Comment: Моя коток, также как и мой рыс, - это животное интересное.

Comment: Мистер Георг, - так как и Лео-метр является небезызвестно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

◙ Сначала предлагаю **правило** Розенталя ([*Оборот типа «как и»*](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%B8/#:%7E:text=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5,%D0%B2%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B5%2C%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%BA)):

> **Запятыми** выделяются или отделяются сравнительные обороты с союзом *как* в случаях, если оборот начинается сочетанием *как и*: *К Москве, **как и ко всей стране,** я чувствую свою сыновность, как к старой няньке* (Пауст.); *В её глазах,  **как и во всём лице,** было что-то необычное; Дети, **как и взрослые,** должны быть приучены к соблюдению правил общежития*...

◙ Потом **решение** (с поправками): указанные запятые ставим.

*Мой кoток, также как и **моя рысь,** — это интересное животное.*
*Мой кoток, также как и **мой рыс,** — это интересное животное.*

"Моя рыс" — это не "прокатит". *Мой рыс* — ещё куда ни шло, по аналогии: *крыса — крыс*.
[«Мадам Пэн и ее **крыс**: Мистическая история» — книга К. Стрельниковой.]

*Мистер Георг, **как и Лео-мэтр,** является небезынтересным.*
Слово "так" здесь совершенно не нужно.

*Григорий, **как и прочие солдаты дивизии Вейде,** прибрёл в Новгород* (Олег Усенко. Царский братец из Лефортова полка).
*Выйдя из-под арки с другой стороны, попадаешь, **как и Леопольд Блум,** к церкви Всех Святых на Вестленд-роу* (Элиша Зинде. По улицам «Улисса»).